# Error on retrieving data from Node.js server and cycling in Javascript client

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a node.js server to get my posts data.
Basically it get all my documents in the collection with a filter and an order:

```
var ref = db.collection('posts');
var visible = request.query.visible;
var query = null;

if(visible === true) {
  query = ref.where('visible', '==', true)
    .orderBy('creation_date', 'desc');
}
else {
  query = ref.orderBy('creation_date', 'desc');
}

query.get()
  .then(res => {
    result.send(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    result.status(500).send(err);
  });
```

On the client-side I do an Ajax request to my server and cycle the items I received.

**Ajax Request GetPosts() Function inside firestore class**

```
var firebaseApiRequest = AjaxRequest(`${this.apiUrl}/posts`, 'GET');
  firebaseApiRequest.send();

  firebaseApiRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      if(this.status === 200) resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      else {
        resolve([]);
      }
    }
  }
```

**index.js function to display the posts i received from the server**

```
let firestoreAPI = new firestore();
firestoreAPI.GetPosts().then(posts => {
  posts.forEach(post => {
    console.log(post);
    let json = post.data();
    json.id = post.id;
    postsList.push(json);
  });
  BuildPosts();
});
```

On node.js server all work fine and i got the posts json back. When the code reaches **posts.forEach** i got this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: posts.forEach is not a function

That is the Json i got back from the server (i have removed some sensitive data)

```
{
"_query": {
    "_referencePath": {
        "segments": ["posts"]
    },
    "_fieldFilters": [],
    "_fieldOrders": [{
        "_field": {
            "segments": ["creation_date"],
            "_formattedName": "creation_date"
        },
        "_direction": "DESCENDING"
    }],
    "_queryOptions": {}
},
"_readTime": "2018-01-27T18:50:36.587401000Z",
"_materializedDocs": [{
    "_fieldsProto": {
        "clicks": {
            "integerValue": "6",
            "valueType": "integerValue"
        },
        "title": {
            "stringValue": "Corso gratuito sviluppo giochi con Unity 3D",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "creation_date": {
            "integerValue": "1516813022363",
            "valueType": "integerValue"
        },
        "author": {
            "stringValue": "xcoding.it",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "url": {
            "stringValue": "https://www.xcoding.it/corso/le-basi-di-unity-3d/",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "creation_user": {
            "stringValue": "marcodz554@gmail.com",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "edit_date": {
            "integerValue": "1516871809344",
            "valueType": "integerValue"
        },
        "edit_user": {
            "stringValue": "marcodz554@gmail.com",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "visible": {
            "booleanValue": true,
            "valueType": "booleanValue"
        },
        "text": {
            "stringValue": "Corso base per i principianti con Unity3D che ricopre la maggior parte dei punti per scoprire questo engine. Completamente in lingua italiana e ben redatto, unica pecca la mancanza di video-guide annesse.",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "type": {
            "stringValue": "corso",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        }
    },
    "_readTime": "2018-01-27T18:50:36.587401000Z",
    "_createTime": "2018-01-24T09:01:41.929842000Z",
    "_updateTime": "2018-01-26T14:15:31.739188000Z"
}, {
    "_fieldsProto": {
        "creation_date": {
            "integerValue": "1516812951013",
            "valueType": "integerValue"
        },
        "author": {
            "stringValue": "brackeys.com",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "url": {
            "stringValue": "https://www.youtube.com/user/Brackeys",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "creation_user": {
            "stringValue": "marcodz554@gmail.com",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "visible": {
            "booleanValue": true,
            "valueType": "booleanValue"
        },
        "text": {
            "stringValue": "Canale Youtube rifornito ogni due giorni circa con video inerenti a Unity3D. Ottime spiegazioni e facile da capire con una conoscenza base della lingua inglese.",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "type": {
            "stringValue": "canale",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "clicks": {
            "integerValue": "4",
            "valueType": "integerValue"
        },
        "title": {
            "stringValue": "Brackeys",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        }
    },
    "_readTime": "2018-01-27T18:50:36.587401000Z",
    "_createTime": "2018-01-24T12:06:00.792552000Z",
    "_updateTime": "2018-01-25T11:04:57.606426000Z"
}]
}
```

Comment: It'll be easier to see what's going on if you `console.log(this.responseText)`, but logic indicates that this doesn't return an array.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated the problem description with the Json i got from server.

Answer (score 1):

Given the JSON you show, it indeed won't have a `forEach` on the object that you return.

The only array I see is `_materializedDocs`, which you can loop over with:

```
posts._materializedDocs.forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved building a custom Json on server side with docs DATA and IDs.